# Write/Read utf-8 from sqlite3 db with Python web interface

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, sqlite

I have a textfield for user-input that adds data to a sqlite3 database with a Python-script. But my script breaks once the user enters a text with utf-8 characters:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Since the db string-entries are all unicode I suspect that my INSERT statement might cause the problem, but how can I pass utf-8-characters from the text input into the sqlite3 db, without converting them to %s strings? This is how I add the messages from the textarea:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('%s', '%s', NULL)" % (threadinput , strip_html(newmessage)))
```

This is where I print the messages from the db, raising the UnicodeError:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('msg.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE thread ='%s' ORDER BY nr ASC" % threadinput)
rows = c.fetchall()
count = 1
for row in rows:
        print "<li>Message Nr. %s: %s</li>" % (count, row)
        count += 1
conn.close()
```

Comment: In sqlite3 you need to use `?` or `:name` for parameter replacement...  Use `values (?, ?, NULL)` instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is how I add the messages from the textarea:
>
> ```
> c.execute("INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('%s', '%s', NULL)" % (threadinput , strip_html(newmessage)))
> ```

Well *there's* your problem! </adam_savage>

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO messages VALUES (?, ?, NULL)", (threadinput , strip_html(newmessage)))
```